# Save and get data in the same table by different relationships - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table in my database called `place_events`

I need to save two types of places in that table, these types are, one `main` and some `alternate` (optional)

[My view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdf0l.png)

My table:

```
create_table "place_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "event_place_id",   limit: 4
    t.string   "event_place_type", limit: 255
    t.integer  "event_id",         limit: 4
  end
```

I'm trying to save my data by different relationships so that later I can get them

```
if !params[:precint].nil?
      precint_hash = JSON.parse(params[:precint])
      precint_hash = precint_hash.except('id', 'description', '$$hashKey', 'logo')
      precint = PrecintEvent.new(precint_hash)
      @event.build_place_event(event_place: precint)
    end

    if params[:alternate_precints]
      precints_hash = JSON.parse(params[:alternate_precints])
      precints_hash.each do |precint|
        precint = precint.except('id', 'description', '$$hashKey', 'logo')
        precint = PrecintEvent.new(precint)
        @event.alternate_place_events.build(event_place: precint)
      end
    end
```

that code works and saves the data in my table `place_events` but my problem is when I want to get them, get the principal and get the alternates

I try these relationships in my model `event.rb`:

```
has_one :place_event
has_many :alternate_place_events, class_name: PlaceEvent.name, foreign_key: 'event_id'
```

but this does not work

This is correct:

```
@event.place_event
#<PlaceEvent id: 8, created_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", updated_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", event_place_id: 8, event_place_type: "PrecintEvent", city_event_id: nil, event_id: 15>
```

This is correct:
I should not get the data with id number 8

```
@event.alternate_place_events

        #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
    #<PlaceEvent id: 8, created_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", updated_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", event_place_id: 8, event_place_type: "PrecintEvent", city_event_id: nil, event_id: 15>, 
    #<PlaceEvent id: 9, created_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", updated_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", event_place_id: 9, event_place_type: "PrecintEvent", city_event_id: nil, event_id: 15>, 
    #<PlaceEvent id: 10, created_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", updated_at: "2019-06-14 00:27:50", event_place_id: 10, event_place_type: "PrecintEvent", city_event_id: nil, event_id: 15>]>
```

**How could I do this? Is it possible to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to handle multiple types of records in the same table is to use `enum`.

For example, in the `event.rb`

```
class Event< ActiveRecord::Base
  enum event_place_type: [ :main, :alternate]
end
```

That means, you can only save two types of strings to your event_place_type column, that is "main" and "alternate".

Whenever you want to find the main records you can do so:
@event.main
Or if you need the alternate
@event.alternate
(Note that Rails will treat this values as integers in the DB, like 0, 1, 2)

This is just a suggestion, because you will not need more than one relationship for the same tables, and if you just want to show one record from 'main' you can apply some logic in the model, or just @event.main.first or last.

Here is the documentation on Enum:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

I hope this helps